# Jquery change href for specific element in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

There's an array with 3 links all attached to the same class.

If I type `$(".more").attr("href", "http://url.com")`, it changes every link associated to that class.

If I type `$(".more")[1].href`, it'll point to the link for the second element in the array, but I can't get the `.attr` to work.

How do I change a specific element in an array with jQuery?

Comment: `$('.more').eq(1).attr(...)` if you use brackets, the element is returned as an HTMLElement, not a _jQuery Element_. use `eq()` to select a single element out of the collection

Comment: When you invoke `$(".more")[1]`, you're getting the DOM object, which is no longer wrapped in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$(".more")[1]`, you're getting the DOM object that's no longer wrapped in jQuery. To get the jQuery object, [use the `eq` function instead](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

In your case, this is the line you'll need:

```
$(".more").eq(1).attr("href", "http://url.com");
```